# Query an array field with an array query parameter Node/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose

I have one of the Route schema fields which is an array of String `weekdays: {type:[String], required:false}` which can contain 0 to 7 Strings ( usage days ), so with the query I'm also passing an array (weekdays range) to find any record which weekdays array field contains at least one of the query weekdays array values.

I'm using `weekdays: {$elemMatch: {weekdays}` but it's not working as the field should match all criteria hence all the query array.
I also tried the`$in` operator but it crashes node with the message:

```
Mongoose Route.findRoutes city weekdays time ranges public error:  CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ weekdays: '[tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun]' }" (type Object) at path "weekdays" for model "Route"
    at model.Query.exec (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4470:21)
    at model.Query.Query.find (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2085:8)
    at Function.find (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2093:13)
    at exports.findRoutes (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/route.controller.js:28:15)
    at handleReturn (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7
    at handleReturn (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at exports.clientApiKeyValidation (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/auth_utils.js:15:10)
    at handleReturn (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7
    at handleReturn (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ weekdays: '[tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun]' }"`,
  kind: 'string',
  value: { weekdays: '[tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun]' },
  path: 'weekdays',
  reason: null,
  valueType: 'Object'
}
node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/route.controller.js:54:28
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4868:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4870:15
```

What's the correct operator to use in this case or how can the two arrays can be cross checked ?
As always many thanks for your time and help.

This is the method in the controller:

```
if (city && region && country && isPublic && weekdays && minTime && maxTime) {
        Route.find(
            {
                city: city,
                region: region,
                country: country,
                
                isPublic: isPublic,
                time: {
                    $gte: minTime,
                    $lte: maxTime
                },
                weekdays: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        weekdays}
                }

            },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mongoose Route.findRoutes city weekdays time ranges public error: ', err);
                    res.status(503).send({
                        error: 'Internal error'
                    });
                }
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    console.log('Mongoose Route.findRoutes city weekdays time ranges public: ', result);
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message: 'Routes found.',
                        data: result
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Mongoose Route.findRoutes city weekdays time ranges public : No routes found.');
                    res.status(404).send({ message: 'No routes found' });
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

and this is the schema:

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    region: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    userName: { type: String, required: true },

    routeName: { type: String, required: true },
    routeDistance: { type: String, required: true },
    routeDuration: { type: String, required: true },
    rawTrack: { type: [Object], required: true },
    // snappedToRoad: { type: [Object], required: false },
    tracked: { type: [Object], required: false },
    filtered: { type: [Object], required: false },
    isPublic: {type: Boolean, required: false, default: false},
    weekdays: {type:[String], required:false},
    time : {type:String, required: false}

},
    {
        timestamps: true,
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
        toJSON: { virtuals: true }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you used the wrong syntax with `$in` because it is the right way to go in this case. If your `weekdays` variable is an array, you can use below code:

```
Route.find({
  ...
  weekdays: { $in: weekdays },
  ...
})
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/34UTgJXz_1w)

Comment: Indeed the problem was caused by the  two brackets.. as `{$in: {weekdays}`. Thanks, I didn't notice the syntax error and started manipulating the incoming array in weird ways lol.